# Switching from editing on directly on remote server to PHPstorm local development?

Tags: localhost, local-installation, ide

I was recently told that my workflow would be improved if I switched from using emacs to edit the files on a staging server directly to using PHPstorm to make changes to my website.  I am fairly lost on what I should do to set PHPstorm up properly as well as correctly cloning my website.  I have set the website up using version control however it's not all of the content for the site, just the relevant files in the wp-content directory.  Where should I start in getting my local environment set up properly?

Thanks!